# All items getting picked up when collided instead of single in pygame RPG

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

I created this code to roll an item drop when an enemy dies:

> ```
>     if len(current_enemy_group.sprites()) > 0:
>         for goblin in current_enemy_group:
>             if goblin.health <= 0:
>                 current_goblin_x = goblin.rect.x
>                 current_goblin_y = goblin.rect.y
>                 attack = False
>                 current_enemy_group.remove(goblin)
>                 all_sprites.remove(spell1)
>                 drop = random.randrange(0, 2, 1)
>                 if key_drop == False:
>                     key_drop = True
>                     key = Pickups(keyIMG, 35, 11)
>                     current_pickups_group.add(key)
>                     key.rect.x = current_goblin_x
>                     key.rect.y = current_goblin_y
>                     print("KEY DROPPED")
>
>                 elif drop == 1:
>                     gold = Pickups(goldIMG, 24, 25)
>                     current_pickups_group.add(gold)
>                     gold.rect.x = current_goblin_x
>                     gold.rect.y = current_goblin_y
>
>
>                 elif drop == 0:
>                     print ("Item Drop")
>                     ##WHAT TYPE OF ITEM
>                     item_type = random.randrange(0, 3, 1)
>                     if item_type == 0:
>                         print("Potion Drop")
>                         potion = Pickups(potionIMG, 9, 9)
>                         current_pickups_group.add(potion)
>                         potion.rect.x = current_goblin_x
>                         potion.rect.y = current_goblin_y
> ```

```
                    elif item_type == 1:
                        print("Armor Drop")
                        if cloth_armor == False:
                            player.armor = 15
                            cloth_armor = True
                    elif item_type == 2:
                        print ("Weapon Drop")
                        item_rarity = random.randrange(0, 100, 1) + magic_find
                        if item_rarity >= 90:
                            print("ULTIMATE WEAPON AQCUIRED")
                            player.damage =1000000


                goblin.health = 2000
```

And I added this for collision detection/item pickup:

```
    item_pickup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, current_pickups_group, False)
    if enemy_alive == True:
        print (gold.rect.x, potion.rect.x, key.rect.x)

    if item_pickup:
        for gold in item_pickup:
            player.gold += 1000
            print("You have acquired 1000 gold")
            current_pickups_group.remove(gold)
            current_pickups_group.update


        for potion in item_pickup:
            player.potion_count += 1
            print("+1 potions")
            current_pickups_group.remove(potion)
            current_pickups_group.update


        for key in item_pickup:
            have_key = True
            print("You now have the Gate Key")
            current_pickups_group.remove(key)
            current_pickups_group.update
            sound_KEYGRAB.play(loops=0, maxtime=0)
```

And so every time my player sprite collides with the current_pickups_group sprites (when I walk into the item to collect it),it runs through all three for loops in item_pickup. It counts as gold, a potion, and a key in that order.

I printed gold,potion, and key x coordinates to see where they were,
and when I collected something it would change all x coord to whatever I just picked up.

I can't figure out why this is happening, and I spent many hours with trial and error.

Even though gold, potion, and key are different instances, they keep getting treated as the same thing when I iterate over item_pickup.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could let me know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up fixing this problem. I will post my fixed code so that if anyone else runs into this problem, then they may be able to gain some insight from this.

Basically, as i'll show below, instead of naming each instance that I passed through as an individual item, I called them all drop. I still needed a way to individually reference each new instance, because they're all named drop right?
So I added a new argument within the Pickups class called label, and passed through a specific label upon creating the new instance aka item drop.

```
    if len(current_enemy_group.sprites()) > 0:

        for goblin in current_enemy_group:

            if goblin.health <= 0:
                current_goblin_x = goblin.rect.x
                current_goblin_y = goblin.rect.y
                attack = False
                current_enemy_group.remove(goblin)
                all_sprites.remove(spell1)
                drop = random.randrange(0, 2, 1)
                if key_drop == False:
                    key_drop = True
```

> ```
>                     drop = Pickups(keyIMG, 35, 11, "key")
> ```

```
                    current_pickups_group.add(drop)
                    drop.rect.x = current_goblin_x
                    drop.rect.y = current_goblin_y
                    print("KEY DROPPED")

                elif drop == 1:

                    drop = Pickups(goldIMG, 24, 25, "gold")

                    current_pickups_group.add(drop)
                    drop.rect.x = current_goblin_x
                    drop.rect.y = current_goblin_y


                elif drop == 0:
                    print ("Item Drop")
                    ##WHAT TYPE OF ITEM
                    item_type = random.randrange(0, 3, 1)
                    if item_type == 0:
                        print("Potion Drop")
                        drop = Pickups(potionIMG, 9, 9, "potion")

                        current_pickups_group.add(drop)
                        drop.rect.x = current_goblin_x
                        drop.rect.y = current_goblin_y
```

Then I just modified the "on pickup" code to reference all instances with label "x".

```
     item_pickup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, current_pickups_group, False)

    if item_pickup:
        for drop in item_pickup:
```

> ```
>             if drop.label == "gold":
> ```

```
                player.gold += 1000
                print("You have acquired 1000 gold")
                current_pickups_group.remove(drop)


            if drop.label == "potion":
                player.potion_count += 1
                print("+1 potions")
                current_pickups_group.remove(drop)

            if drop.label == "key":
                have_key = True
                print("You now have the Gate Key")
                current_pickups_group.remove(drop)
                sound_KEYGRAB.play(loops=0, maxtime=0)
```